# Как лучше реализовать модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html

*Код не вставляю т.к. это теория.*

Например, я знаю два способа:

1. вставить модальное окно прям в верстку и открывать или скрывать его при надобности.
2. Создавать окно с помощью JS.

Что выгодней использовать, что меньше нагружает компьютер? Или это зависит от задачи. Например, если нужно модальное окно для ошибки, то лучше его создавать через js, а если это фотогалерея, создать окно при первом клике по фото и потом изменять содержимое окна(если пользователь листает фото).

Answer (score 1):

Создавать или открывать - вот в чём вопрос.
Как удобнее в проекте; нагрузить устройство созданием элементов можно, но для этого надо быть неплохим рукокрюком.
Я предпочитаю открывать уже созданную разметку - её шаблонизатор создаст, а JS получит лишь CSS-путь к ключевым элементам, например:

```js
class Modal{
  static setElements(els){
    Modal._els = els;
  }
  
  constructor(data){
    data = Object.assign({
      header: 'Заголовок',
      body: 'Тело',
      
      ok: () => 1,
      no: () => 0
    }, data);
    
    this._data = data;
  }
  
  show(){
    if(!Modal._els) return;
    
    Modal._els.header.innerHTML = this._data.header;
    Modal._els.body.innerHTML = this._data.body;
    
    Modal._els.yes.addEventListener('click', this._data.yes);
    Modal._els.no.addEventListener('click', this._data.no);
      
    Modal._els.wrapper.classList.toggle('modal_show');
    
    return this;
  }
  
  hide(){
    Modal._els.yes.removeEventListener('click', this._data.yes);
    Modal._els.no.removeEventListener('click', this._data.no);
    
    Modal._els.wrapper.classList.toggle('modal_show');
    
    return this;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let els = {
    header: document.querySelector('#modal__header'),
    body: document.querySelector('#modal__body'),
    footer: document.querySelector('#modal__footer'),
    wrapper: document.querySelector('#modal__wrapper'),
  };
  
  els.yes = els.footer.children[0];
  els.no = els.footer.children[1];
  
  Modal.setElements(els);
  
  document.querySelector('#open').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let modal = (new Modal({
      header: 'Новое уведомление',
      body: 'Я открылся!',
      yes: e => {
        console.info('Да!');
        modal.hide();
      },
      no: e => {
        console.info('Нет!');
        modal.hide();
      }
    })).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#modal__wrapper{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
#modal{
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 20%;
  min-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
}
#modal__header{
  padding: 0 0 5px 7px;;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#modal__body{
  padding: 10px;
}
#modal__footer{
  float: right;
}

.modal_show{
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<div id='modal__wrapper'>
  <div id='modal'>
    <div id='modal__header'>Header</div>
    <div id='modal__body'>Body</div>
    <div id='modal__footer'>
      <input type='button' value='Yes' />
      <input type='button' value='No' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='open' value='Open' />
```

Comment: Я поражаюсь - что за нелюди здесь ставят «–» за хороший ответ?! Надо что-то с этим делать (менять правила)!

Answer (score -1):

Практически во всех HTML фреймворках модальные окна помещаются в код документа. По этому, лучше не изобретать велосипед, а использовать опыт разработчиков.